# Local Test Server Not Working Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, dreamweaver

I'm trying to set up dreamweaver so I can do all my testing locally. I use XAMPP to start an Apache Server listening on port 80. I set up Dreamweaver to use localhost for a testing server. However, whenever I try to preview the page live I get the following error

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'techclub'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\techclub\PHP\query upcoming.php on line 35
Unable to connect!

I checked to make sure there is no weird temp file setting going on and there isnt. I also tested the site live and the page works fine live but not for the test server.

Comment: So did you check if you're using the right credentials? The mere fact that you actually SAW this error message means that Apache and PHP are working properly. You've just used the wrong account to connect to MySQL with.

Comment: How would I check that? I'm running the exact same code live and it works fine so I imagine the credentials are correct.

Comment: I imagine you have different credentials live and locally

Comment: I wouldn't make that assumption. MySQL is telling you that the username/password combo you are using in your PHP is incorrect for that server. Try adding a new user and setting a password, then use that in your PHP.

Comment: I have different credentials live and locally. Put that as an answer and I'll give you points Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to check your credentials, PHP and Apache are working fine locally if you are getting that error.

Comment: This is more of a comment that reiterates what the current comments are saying.

Comment: @marty Sure enough...should I take it down?